# SQL Error[500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "Distributed"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am running following query:

```
Create table kwh_blocks_740
(
KWH_BLOCKS smallint NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION character varying(100) not null
)
DISTRIBUTED BY (KWH_BLOCKS);
```

Please help....how to resolve this
It shows error.

Error:

> SQL Error[500310] [42601]: Amazon Invalid operation: syntax
> error at or near "Distributed"

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Distributed` keyword of table creation in Redshift.
Please check the [Redshift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) to create table. It is `DISTKEY` instead of `DISTRIBUTED BY`.

Your table will look like this.

```
Create table kwh_blocks_740
(
KWH_BLOCKS smallint NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION character varying(100) not null
)
DISTKEY (KWH_BLOCKS);
```